# Subsetting data so that it does not contain values that meet a condition

Tags: r, subset, grepl

I am working with mock Twitter data and I need to filter out retweets, ie tweets starting with "RT ". I am trying to figure out how to subset my dataframe so that tweets containing "RT " are not included in the new dataframe.

I have some experience with RStudio, but primarily have used it on classroom datasets that are already clean and ready to use.

Sample of what my data looks like below

| user | tweet |
| --- | --- |
| user 1 | RT @SomaKudi: In 2017, make your dream a reality. |
| user 1 | @FrankAkolo1 Hello, the Programme, is a 10-year, $100 million commitment to identify, train, mentor & fund 10,000 #AfricanEntrepreneurs |
|  |  |

So far I've tried the following

```
vec <- "RT "

new_df <- df$var[!df$var %in% vec]
```

which stores the entire old dataframe into the new one but as a value.

I've also tried this

```
new_df <- with(df, df[!grepl("RT ", df$var)])
```

which returns the following error message

! Can't subset columns with `!grepl("RT ", df$var)`.
✖ Logical subscript `!grepl("RT ", df$var)` must be size 1 or 5, not 3115.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: `df_new <- with(df, df[!grepl("^RT", tweet), ])` saves a new data frame without tweets that start with `RT`.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, what Andre said. What you want to do is create a new data structure for which no entry starts with RT. This is relatively simple and requires almost no knowledge of regex. The caret character means, roughly, "text start". So a regex of "`^RT`" means all entries which begin with "RT". Personally, I shy away from using `with` so I would do:

```r
DF_new <- DF[!grepl("^RT", DF$tweet), ]
```

This takes `DF` (better to not use `df` since that's a `stats` function to return the pdf of the F distribution), searches the `tweet` column for entries beginning with `RT` and returns all columns for each row which **does not** begin with RT into the `DF_new` data.frame. For example:

```r
DF <- data.frame(user = c("user 1", "user 1", "user 2"),
                 tweet = c("RT @SomaKudi: In 2017, make your dream a reality.",
                           "@FrankAkolo1 Hello, the Programme, is a 10-year, $100 million commitment to identify, train, mentor & fund 10,000 #AfricanEntrepreneurs",
                           "This is a test."))
str(DF)

'data.frame':   3 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ user : chr  "user 1" "user 1" "user 2"
 $ tweet: chr  "RT @SomaKudi: In 2017, make your dream a reality." "@FrankAkolo1 Hello, the Programme, is a 10-year, $100 million commitment to identify, train, mentor & fund 10,0"| __truncated__ "This is a test."

DF_new <- DF[!grepl("^RT", DF$tweet), ]
str(DF_new)
'data.frame':   2 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ user : chr  "user 1" "user 2"
 $ tweet: chr  "@FrankAkolo1 Hello, the Programme, is a 10-year, $100 million commitment to identify, train, mentor & fund 10,0"| __truncated__ "This is a test."
```